# enviar correo con archivo adjunto PHPMAILER

Tags: php, phpmailer

tengo este codigo pero no se que hago mal que no puedo enviar correo con archivo adjunto

```
$mail->CharSet    = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                      //Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP(true);                                            //Send using SMTP
            $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication           
            //$mail->Mailer     = 'smtp';
            $mail->Username   = 'coopfe@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
            $mail->Password   = '2022coope';                               //SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;//PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption           
            $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

        

//Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('coopfe@gmail.com', 'Coop'); //cosmolfe@gmail.com
            $mail->addAddress('ausb@gmail.com', 'cliente');     //Add a recipient
            
            //Attachments
            $mail->addAttachment($dato1);         //Add attachments
            $mail->addAttachment($dato2);    //Optional name

            //Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Documentos';
            $mail->Body    = 'Señor le Enviamossus datos';
                
            $mail->send();
```

no se que puedo estar haciendo mal ya que segun lei desde mayo no se puede utilizar google para hacer este tipo de envios, por favor ayuda.

Este es el mensaje que resibo:

```
2022-12-01 03:06:55 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2022-12-01 03:06:55 Connection: opened
2022-12-01 03:06:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP b19-20020a9d6b93000000b0066c34486aa7sm1608909otq.73 - gsmtp
2022-12-01 03:06:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 190.180.62.136
2022-12-01 03:06:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [177.222.44.34]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2022-12-01 03:06:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2022-12-01 03:06:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2022-12-01 03:06:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 190.180.62.136
2022-12-01 03:06:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [177.222.44.34]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2022-12-01 03:06:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2022-12-01 03:06:57 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2022-12-01 03:06:57 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2022-12-01 03:06:57 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2022-12-01 03:06:57 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2022-12-01 03:07:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b19-20020a9d6b93000000b0066c34486aa7sm1608909otq.73 - gsmtp
2022-12-01 03:07:20 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b19-20020a9d6b93000000b0066c34486aa7sm1608909otq.73 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2022-12-01 03:07:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2022-12-01 03:07:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection b19-20020a9d6b93000000b0066c34486aa7sm1608909otq.73 - gsmtp
2022-12-01 03:07:20 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Ocurrio un Error el Enviar: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

este mensaje reviso y es evidente que algo anda mal... espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Te aparece algún mensaje?

Comment: Creo que en [este enlace](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=es&text=Username%20and%20Password%20not%20accepted.%20Learn%20more%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fp%3DBadCredentials&op=translate) encontrarás la respuesta a tu problema y podrás avanzar en su resolución.

Comment: Te está diciendo claro que el usuario y/o contraseña que usas para autentificar tu cuenta de Gmail no son correctos.

Comment: eso mismo pense, pero esos son los credenciales de la cuenta gmail, ... lei que desde mayo de este anio gmail desabilito para poder conectarse desde aplicaciones externas no se si eso tenga algo que ver o existe otra manera de enviar correo con datos adjuntos.

Comment: Gmail tiene la opción de generar passwords para Aplicaciones Externas, es mas sino me equivoco así es la única forma en que te permite enviar mensajes desde entornos como PHP. Verifique que el password que esta usando (que espero ese pass sea fake porque sino peligra su seguridad) no sea el original del correo sino uno generado para ser usado en apps eternas.

Gmail no deja generar pass para apps externas cuando usas la suite de gemail con tu propio dominio. ejemplo coopfe@coopfe.com dentro de la suite de Gmail. Eso me sucede a mi por ejemplo...

Comment: En ese caso es mejor usar [la API de Google](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) para enviar tus correos electrónicos desde Gmail. Serviría también para el caso que expone @Erika.

Comment: asi es Erika los datos del email son fake, pero me informare un poco mas sobre lo que recomiendas haber como me sale y sobre las API de Google, A. Cedano tb buscare un poco de informacion porque la verdad ando con este lios semanas y no puede salir de el..y decidi buscar ayuda.